# Erro function not defined

Tags: php, funções

Segue o código:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['algumacoisa']) && !empty($_GET['algumacoisa'])) {
    $user = "useradmin";
    $pass = "senha123";
    mysql_connect("localhost", $user, $pass);
    mysql_select_db("meubancodedados");
    $consulta    = mysql_query("select * from teste where Status= '' ");
    $total       = 0;
    $atualizadas = 0;
    while ($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($consulta)) {
        $total += 1;
        $idpedido = $linha["Pedido"];
        if (verifica($idpedido))
            $atualizadas += 1;
    }
    function verifica($pedido) // Inicio Function Verifica
    {
        // Email cadastrado no Pagamento Digital
        $email       = "emailficticio@outlook.com";
        // Obtenha seu TOKEN entrando no menu Ferramentas do Pagamento Digital
        $token       = "1231232132131";
        $urlPost     = "https://www.pagamentodigital.com.br/transacao/consulta/";
        $transacaoId = $pedido;
        $pedidoId    = $pedido;
        $tipoRetorno = 1;
        $codificacao = 1;
        $ch          = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlPost);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
            "id_transacao" => $transacaoId,
            "id_pedido" => $pedidoId,
            "tipo_retorno" => $tipoRetorno,
            "codificacao" => $codificacao
        ));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($email . ":" . $token)
        ));
        /* XML ou Json de retorno */
        $resposta = curl_exec($ch);
        /* Capturando o http code para tratamento dos erros na requisição*/
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);
        if ($httpCode != "200") {
            echo $httpCode;
            echo "algum erro ocorreu.. tente novamente!";
        } else {
            $xml       = simplexml_load_string($resposta);
            $codstatus = $xml->cod_status;
            $email     = $xml->cliente_email;
            $nome      = $xml->cliente_nome;
            $meio      = $xml->cod_meio_pagamento;

            if ($meio != 10) {

                $meio = "Cartao";
            }
            if ($codstatus == 3) {
                mysql_query(" UPDATE teste SET Status = 'Aprovado' WHERE Pedido = '$pedido' ");
                mysql_query(" UPDATE teste SET Email = '$email' WHERE Pedido = '$pedido' ");
                mysql_query(" UPDATE teste SET Nome = '$nome' WHERE Pedido = '$pedido' ");
                mysql_query(" UPDATE teste SET Meio = '$meio' WHERE Pedido = '$pedido' ");
                return true;
            }

        }
    } // Fim function verifica



    echo "<xml><total>{$total}</total>
<atualizadas>{$atualizadas}</atualizadas></xml>";


} else {

    echo "<meta charset='utf-8'/> Página inválida, movida temporariamente.";
}

?>
```

Problema é que, dá este erro:
*Fatal error: Call to undefined function verifica() in /home/dominio/public_html/ctr/atualiza.php on line 13*
A linha apontada ali é esta:

```
if ( verifica($idpedido) )
```

Resumindo do porquê vim aqui.. se eu tirar este IF/ELSE(aquele que verifica se houve uma requisição GET na página), volta a funcionar sem problemas.
Sim, estou dando um get na página, algo como .php?algumacoisa=teste, para minha página entrar, mas ai que dá o erro.

Porquê será, não faz sentido para mim!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não consegui entender muito bem seu código, e não sei se isso influi no PHP, mas tenta declarar a função antes de chama-la. Como atentou o @bfavaretto você está declarando a sua função dentro do `if (isset($_GET['algumacoisa']) && !empty($_GET['algumacoisa'])) {`

O recomendado é que você declare a função fora do `if()`, para que ela exista independente do que `if()`.

```
if ( verifica($idpedido) ) 
     $atualizadas+=1;
}
function verifica($pedido) {
```

Tente assim:

```
<?php
function verifica($pedido) // Inicio Function Verifica
    {
    ...
    }
if(isset($_GET['algumacoisa']) && !empty($_GET['algumacoisa']))
   {
   ... Aqui dentro você faz a chamada da função verifica().
   }
php?>
```

Se você declarar uma função dentro do if ela só passará a existir se a condição do if for satisfeita. Exemplificando:

```
<?php

$criarFuncao = true;

funcao1(); //Essa função será chamada pois mesmo ela sendo declarada no final do código ela sempre será declarada.

if($criarFuncao) {
    function funcao2() {
        echo "A função 2 só será criada quando a condição if($criarFuncao) for satisfeita.";
   } 
}

if($criarFuncao) funcao2(); //Se a condição $criarFuncao for verdadeira, a função será criada no if anterior, e poderá ser chamada na condição atual.

function funcao1() {
    echo "Funcao 1 é criada independente de qualquer condição e pode ser chamada antes ou depois da declaração.";
}

php?>
```

Créditos:

[Documentação User-defined functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php)
 e Comentários do bfavaretto.

Comment: No código do autor, a função está declarada dentro de um `if`. Nesses casos você tem razão, ela precisa ser declarada antes de ser chamada. Mas não precisaria se estivesse fora do `if`. Confuso? PHP!

Comment: À vontade. Vale uma olhada aqui também pra rechear mais a resposta: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php (veja o exemplo 2).

Comment: No fundo, não consigo enxergar um bom motivo para declarar uma função dentro de um `if`. Alterar isso também resolveria o problema.

Comment: Respsota editada, acho que ficou melhor agora, se eu tiver falado alguma besteira me corrija. E realmente também não vejo um bom motivo pra declarar uma função dentro de um if.

Comment: Li este link que o bfavaretto indicou, e lá está bem claro que a função não precisa ser declarada antes do uso dela, a não ser em casos condicionais, que é o caso do uso do IF/ELSE..

Em relação ao problema, declarei antes da condição e pegou perfeitamente.
Valeu a todos!